# How should I model a single entity that has data from multiple data sources?

Tags: oop, database-design, relational-database, data-modeling

Multiple data sources are used to provide mostly the same data about cars. Users will be able to view and compare car data from each source.

For two types of cars, three data sources are used to provide data about the cars. The three data sources will always be the same.

For other types of car, only two data sources are used. One data source will vary among 15 different data sources depending on the type of car. The other data source will remain fixed (and be one of the three noted in the above paragraph).

For a given type of car, a data source may have data (e.g. price) about a car that is not present in the other data sources. In some cases, one data source may have a car that does not exist in the other (two or three) data sources.

Each car will need to mapped to the same car among its different data sources. The system will generally determine the mapping. In some cases, an admin will need to look at the car data and determine the same car is being referred to in the different data sources.

How should I model this in a relational database and OOP? Should each source-car become a table/class (e.g. KellyBlueBookCar)? Or should I model to have a single table/class, Car, with a DataSource column/field?

Comment: Having a single table seems the flexible way to go. Do you see an advantage in having separate tables for each source?

Answer (score 0):

Your database has a minimum of three tables, and really should have many more:

The first is for the car type, which really could have relations to many more--including brand, model, year, and maybe trim, option package, etc.

The second is for what you call the source, which you may want to assign a more specific name, such as car_data_provider or something.

The third contains the actual data, and has foreign keys to the first two, plus the actual data you're interested in (price, etc.).

Looking at the OOP classes, it really depends on many factors relating to your general architecture and your use cases.  If you're familiar with domain driven design, then Car Type suggests itself as the aggregate root.  At any rate, I would make Car Type the enriched object that contains source data.